# I enabled a webhook for a 3rd party service and created a custom php script to see whats happening when this hook fires, but I see nothing happening

Tags: php, post

I have a subscription to a 3rd party service called MARCUS and I just enabled a webhook whenever the service updates. I created a php script and pointed this webhook to it, but I don't see anything happening on my php script. I currently have the php file email me, but the emails are blank.

I tried to receive it via a $_POST and have it output, but I only get array printed out. Is there a php example of how to receive a webhook and print something onto the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you won't see any webhook data, is because you're using **$_POST** incorrectly. **$_POST** is mainly used for web forms and file uploads. What you should be using is **php://input** as that takes in **RAW post data** whenever a post is made to the php file. And you won't see anything because the webhook fires and its not firing to your browser. The only way to see something is to write it to a file whenever the page is called so you can see it in action.

Here is a simple PHP example to see the output:

```
<?php

//Create a botlog.txt file so we can log what's happening whenever this page loads.
$fWrite = fopen("botlog.txt","a");
                                                                                                                                                                                                 //Write to the file, a test message even if we receive an EMPTY POST. So we can debug.
$hello = fwrite($fWrite, "\n\n\n HELLO MARCUS! --- Timestamp: ". time() ."\n\n");

//Write all the web headers that get sent when the page loads. Everytime a page loads,
// there are http headers being sent from the client to the server and vice versa.
//This is so we can debug what is actually happening.
$headers = fwrite($fWrite, print_r(getallheaders(), true));

//Instead of using the $_POST variable for webhooks, we use php://input.
// php://input allows to read raw POST data. $_POST is a superglobal variable, mainly
// used for wrap data with headers application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// (when you submit forms) or multipart/form-data (file uploads)
$decoded = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

//Write the php://input to the botlog file. Have another terminal open and "tail -f botlog.txt" to see the data show up live as you reload the page or when a webhook fires.
$wrote = fwrite($fWrite, print_r($decoded, true));

//close writing the file.
fclose($fWrite);
?>
```